# Automatic installation of chrome extensions via managed policy json doesn't work

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a managed policy for an automatic installation of chrome extensions.

For me the JSON File seems right and under [chrome://policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr6f2.jpg) I get the feedback that everything is ok, but chrome doesn't install the extensions.

What is wrong or what have I missed?

Following JSON File:

```
{

  "ExtensionSettings": {

    "cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm": {

      "installation_mode": "force_installed",

      "update_url":

        "https://client2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

    },

    "pcjlckhhhmlefmobnnoolakplfppdchi": {

      "installation_mode": "force_installed",

      "update_url":

        "https://client2.google.com/service/update2/crx"

    },

  }

}
```

I expect, that the two chrome extensions will be installed automatically after restart chrome.

Comment: Where did you get update_url? Here it has an `s`: `https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx`

Comment: You made my day!!! That was the problem. Ten times checking the url and don't see it. Thank you!!!